# Is there a first row css selector for flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to target all the elements in the first row of a flexbox layout. A first row selector would be really useful but I can't find one. Just wondering if there is such a selector.

Comment: No there is not, but if amount of children is known, nth-child is an hint :)

Comment: There is no way to select an entire row in flexbox. If you know the number of flex items in a row, you can target them as a group.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Cheers